# Start gallery for choosing image directly

Tags: android, android-gallery

Is there a way to start the gallery directly?

Currently:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_CONSTANT);
```

This will prompt the user for an app, but I want to skip this step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the `Gallery` `package` name and the Main `Activity` class name.

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

Query the supported apps to Pick Images

```
List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

Now , retrieve the package name from `ActivityInfo`

```
  for (ResolveInfo info :apps) {
        String packageName = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        String activityName = info.activityInfo.name;
        if(packageName.contains("gallery")){
            // gallery intent
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            galleryIntent.setClassName(packageName,activityName);
            // start the gallery Activity
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
            break;
        }
    }
```

*Note : hardcoding package name as gallery in not right approach, if the package name change in later Android version, this wont work. But the current android version has package name with gallery.*